# Visual Studio 2022 Preview Error Building with .net Maui

Tags: .net, maui

I got excited about .NET MAUI and download a fresh version of Visual Studio 2022.  Once downloaded I created a new solution/project for a .NET MAUI App.  It installed the dummy project by default.  After that, I clicked the build for `Windows Machine`.  It starts to build and ends up getting an error shown below.

[image]

At this screen I selected `Yes` to continue.  And Received the following error message.

[image]

After clearing this error message, I went into configuration manager as instructed by the message.  Only to find that `Deploy` is in fact checked already.  Am I missing something?

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I guess you should download the windows SDK for MAUI

Comment: FIrst: There's a reason that the "No" button was highlighted on msg "There were deployment errors. Continue?". Select "No" when that happens. The only reason to select "Yes", is if you want to run a PREVIOUS build, despite the failure of your current build. That's almost never what you want to do. In this case, there is no previous build (you've never succeeded in building this app), so there is nothing to deploy. That message in the second dialog was misleading.

Comment: Second, when there are errors, they will show in the "Errors" pane of Visual Studio. Copy/Paste into question the text (not as an image) of any errors.

Comment: The error that shows up is DEP0700: Registration of the app failed

Comment: Hi , could we known the version of your visual studio ? And have you tried on other platform like android and iOS simulator ?

Comment: The problem seems to be because my project was located on a mapped network drive.  I moved it to C drive and everything worked as intended